# GWT addSubmitCompleteHandler called twice

Tags: java, gwt, submit, double-submit-problem

I have a form panel (myForm) with a submit button added onto a simple panel. Every time the submit is pressed myForm.addSubmitCompleteHandler is called twice

```
      mySubmit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {         
                myForm.submit();
        }});
         ...
         myForm.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                // what ever's here happens twice
            }
        });
```

I've double checked my code and ordering and placing of widgets and panels. What could possibly be causing this?

What I am trying to achieve is an alert that submission is complete.

Comment: There is not enough information to find the root of this problem. GWT used to have a similar issue in IE8, but it was a long time ago: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3897

Comment: What's the response from the server? Is there some kind of redirection? When debugging your code, are the SubmitCompleteHandlers the same instance or 2 separate instances? Are the SubmitCompleteEvents the same instance or 2 separate instances?

Comment: Yes they seem to be the same instance.

Comment: It seems to happen only in IE and every time I press submit the number of times it's called doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding the line

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in the addClickHandler of the submit button helps. Also make sure you don't have duplicate setAction Calls for the form